# Checking an array for duplicates on a SQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I would love a starting point for this problem.

I have a list of IP's retrieved from a source, the IP's along with ID's get stored in a table.

I want to check the table against my array each time it grabs new data, to make sure the array is not putting a duplicate IP in the said table.

Comment: Thank you ben, the problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong way to think about the problem.  Let the database control the data.  You can ensure no duplicates by defining a constraint or unique index on the IP column (they are pretty much equivalent):

```
create unique index unq_iptable_ip on iptable(ip);
```

Then, if you attempt to insert a duplicate `ip`, the database won't let you.  This ensures data integrity, and the database can do this better than you can (consider what happens if multiple users try to modify the table at the same time).

Comment: Thank you so much, I forgot all about the UNIQUE Index, *Face palm*